# Google Play Developer Console for User to see only 1 app

Tags: google-play

I am building an app for a client and want to give them access to see store listing settings. However, the problem is even I can do app specific rights to a user, he can still see other apps. Even though he cant edit other apps but I don't want him to see the list. I want him to see only his app.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to limit the invited user's right to view your other listings in the Google Play Developer Console. The only rights you can customize are the following:

- Create & edit draft apps
- Edit store listing, pricing & distribution
- Manage Production APKs
- Manage Alpha & Beta APKs
- Manage Alpha & Beta users
- View financial reports
- Reply to reviews
- Edit games
- Publish games

Reference: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2528691

Comment: Thanks Aygul, are you sure about this?

Comment: The answer is based on both my own Google Play Developer Console settings and the official Google Play Help Center article.